# After deploying React JS app in production, latest changes not appear on browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, production-environment

In my react js app If I do some changes in code (CSS or in js) and then deploy on production then it will not reflect the latest changes.

At that time if I want to see new changes I have to open incognito mode and then it will reflect new changes.

So it means it's storing cache right?
If yes How can I prevent this ? or if no then what will be the issue?
Please help

below my index.html file

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <base href="/" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Binks - Best Online Tailoring Service for Women</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

`app.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css"; // main css file
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import loginReducer from './store/reducer/login';
import itemDetailsReducer from './store/reducer/itemDetails';
import App from './App'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  whitelist: ['login','itemDetails'],
  storage
};

const composeEnhancers = (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : null) || compose;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  login: loginReducer,
  itemDetails: itemDetailsReducer,

});

const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(pReducer, composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
));
const  persistor = persistStore(store);
const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <React.StrictMode>
          <Router>
            <App />
          </Router>
        </React.StrictMode>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);
ReactDOM.render(
  app,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Where are you using React? And, if you are using it, you shouldn't be using jQuery.

Comment: I'm using jQuery or importing it for bootstrap only @Andy

Comment: You should be using https://react-bootstrap.github.io/ or https://reactstrap.github.io/ then. But the issue is that there is no React code in your question so we can't possibly help you.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: okay I updated my question. Add app.js file. and what others file I should have to add? @nullptr

Comment: for this issue which react file we have to see please tell so I will put it in question @Andy

Comment: Really we need to understand what build process you're using, and how you're deploying the code. My first comment was just about you telling you're using React but not including any code in the question. And that you were using jQuery. So something's up with the build process, or your deployment process.

Comment: Add enough info so that we can run the code and figure out what the issue is. Even easier, post the code on codesandbox.io and link it.

Comment: deploying it using aws @Andy

Comment: @nullptr but issue occurs only after deploying